# Clarification on bonus hits from passives

Tags: the-secret-world

I need some clarification on the "additional hit" effects from passives in The Secret World:

- Can additional hits perform critical hits?
- Does an additional hit count as "hit"? (like a hit from an ability)
- Can an additional hit proc other passives (or even the passive which triggered the hit)?

I'm guessing they won't do anything from the above (could create very "broken combinations") but I'm not sure since I'm new to the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing with the following passives

- Mind over Matter
- One in the Chamber
- Molecular Exploitation

and by assessing the combat log  I came to the following insight on my questions:

- Can additional hits perform critical hits? **No.**
- Does an additional hit count as "hit"? (like a hit from an ability) **No.**
- Can an additional hit proc other passives (or even the passive which
  triggered the hit)? **No.**

In conclusion the bonus hits from passives give you exactly what they say except for the "hit" part.